# Cross-validation and Training error of Lasso

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Just wanted to check. I have this plot of lasso on training dataset and cross-validation dataset. The red curve is training error while black is cross-validation error.

This curve looks fine right? With increasing alpha, training error would increase while cross-validation error would go down.

Is this understanding correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: looks like the perfect text-book example of a regularization curve (only upside down because you measure error not accuracy) http://gerardnico.com/wiki/_media/data_mining/model_complexity_error_training_test.jpg?w=600

Answer (score 0):

From the plot itself, your understanding is correct. It looks like after the vertical line indicated alpha value, the validation error also started to increase. That may be caused by under-fitting with too much bias from the model.

It is hard to tell whether this plot itself is correct without knowing the data though.